# How to efficiently write a HashMap to a file?

Tags: haskell

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T.IO
import Text.FShow.RealFloat (fshow)

main = do  
  dataA <- T.IO.readFile "pathA"
  dataB <- T.IO.readFile "pathB"
  ...
  let hashmap = -- process dataA and dataB
      hashmapList = map (\(t1,t1Map) -> (t1, map (\(t2,float) -> (t2,fshow float)) (M.toList t1Map))) $ M.toList hashmap
      hashmapString = show hashmapList
  writeFile "path" hashmapString
```

I would like to write hashmap (see the code above), which is of type `M.HashMap T.Text (M.HashMap T.Text Float)`, to a file. I turn hashmap into a List and besides use fshow to show Floats efficiently. Using `show`I then turn the List into a String and write it to a file.

Compiling with -O2 and profiling yields:

```
COST CENTRE          MODULE                %time %alloc

main.hashmapList.\.\ Main                   46.0   50.0
main.hashmapString   Main                   32.5   41.1
main.writeFile       Main                   11.9    0.2
main.hashmapList.\   Main                    3.4    2.7
...
```

So especially turning the Map into a List and turning the List into a String takes a lot of time and space. How can hashmap be written to a file more efficiently?

Comment: Try `Data.Traversable.traverse` or `Data.HashMap.Strict.traverseWithKey`, you can use an IO action there that writes directly to a file, without creating intermediate lists.

Comment: @n.m. Data.Foldable.mapM_ or equivalent is better, since you don't need to collect any results.

Comment: @hammar you should post your comment as an answer, since it resolves the question.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well answer this properly. If you have a filehandle open and an IO action that writes a single entry into this file, then you can use `mapM_` from `Data.Foldable` and just run the action over the entire structure to run it into that file. If you need the keys as well, something like `traverseWithKey` is your friend instead.